# [Beta] Gaming SE Black Edition

Tags: script, style

### Screenshot

[image: Gaming Dark Restyle]

### About

This as simple user script that changes the overall style of Gaming SE sub-site to a darker version.
I made it for myself as I used to do with sites that I tend to visit more (Google, GMail, Youtube, etc.).

Maybe there are other users that like a darker version so I decided to share it.

#### Download

**Greasemonkey Script**

[install / update script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/97655.user.js) – [view source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/97655)

**Userstyles Script**

[Script page](http://userstyles.org/styles/44566)

#### Platform

This script is still in beta and I have tested it only with Firefox + Greasemonkey (Windows XP). **Code is not optimized, it will be in finale release.**

#### Contact

Please, report any bugs or suggestions, I will be happy to fix them and improve the result.

Comment: Nice, though I prefer the userstyle, because its effect is immediate, but scripts only execute when the document is ready.

Comment: Sincerly I prefer userstyle too, in fact I used that to create the script. But if I understood greasemonkey is more cross-browser compatible.